# Creating links to django views using HTMLCalendar

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to override the standard HTMLCalendar formatting to create links in my calendar that go to a specific Django view (the generic "date_based.archive.day" view).  Here's what I've done:

```
class EventsCalendar(HTMLCalendar):
   def formatday(self, day, weekday):
        """
          Return a day as a table cell.
        """
        if day == 0:
            return '<td class="noday">&nbsp;</td>' # day outside month
        else:
            return '<td class="%s"><a href="%s/%s/%d">%d</a></td>' % (self.cssclasses[weekday], '2011', 'dec', day, day)
```

It must be a "python newbie" problem.  Not sure how to pass the year and month into the method to create the link.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access to it in formatmonth method:

```
def formatmonth(self, year, month):
    self.year, self.month = year, month
    return super(EventsCalendar, self).formatmonth(year, month)
```

And then use self.year and self.month in you method.

Comment: How does this work exactly?  I am trying to do something similar but cant figure out how to access the day from the user clicking on the calendar.